# CDaoRecordSet::Seek error

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008

```
CString str = "something";
CDaoDatabase db;
//db open
CDaoRecordset rs(&db);
rs.Open(AFX_DAO_USE_DEFAULT_TYPE,"select * from mydb");
COleVariant searched(str); 
BOOL bFound = rs.Seek("=",searched);
```

For this statement VS2008 returns `error C2664: 'BOOL CDaoRecordset::Seek(LPCTSTR,COleVariant *,COleVariant *,COleVariant *)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'COleVariant' to 'COleVariant *'.`

How can i convert `COleVariant` to a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the address operator '&'

```
BOOL bFound = rs.Seek("=",&searched);
```